# Maximising sum of sine/cosine functions

Tags: trigonometry, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I have got a problem and I would appreciate if one could help.

I have to maximise following function that is the sum of sine/cosine functions:

$$ f(x,y)=a_1 \cos(x) +b_1 \sin(x)+
a_2 \cos(y) +b_2 \sin(y)+
 a_3 \cos(y-x) +b_3 \sin(y-x)
$$
and find the $x$ and $y$ values where the function $f(x,y)$ is maximised assuming that $ 0\leq x,y<2\pi$.
I am aware that I can do first derivative and find the $x$ and $y$. however, I am wondering if one can think of simpler way of maximising this function.

I have realized that for $x=y=0$, the cos functions are maximized and for $x=y=\pi/2$ the sine functions reach max. so, this function is concave in $0<x,y<\pi/2$.

Comment: What the heck does $0 \leq (x,y) < 0$ mean?  First off, what is the comparison between the ordered pair $(x,y)$ and the single real $0$?  Then if you define that comparison, does this relation not say that $0 < 0$?

Comment: typo. sorry! fixed.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you interested in finding the maximum for this particular function in another way?

Comment: This is actually part of a general function that I have derived for optimising a communication system. Assume 
$$ f(x,y,z)=a_1 \cos(x) +b_1 \sin(x)+
a_2 \cos(y) +b_2 \sin(y)+
+a_3 \cos(z) +b_3 \sin(z)+
 a_4 \cos(y-x) +b_4 \sin(y-x)+
a_5 \cos(z-x) +b_5 \sin(z-x)+
a_6 \cos(z-y) +b_6 \sin(z-y)
$$. I am trying to find out if I can find $x,y,z, etc$ variables that maximises the function. by increasing the number of variables, the problem gets more complicated and I get lost in different derivative/second derivative functions

Comment: Ok, I understand. So are you trying to get a more general formula for the solutions when we add each new variable? If you're only interested in a few cases you're probably best off plugging it into some mathematical software.