# maximising sinusoidal functions

Tags: trigonometry, optimization, convex-optimization, trigonometric-series

I have come across a maximisation problem that I do not know how to handle. I have posted the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1867922/maximising-sum-of-sine-cosine-functions?noredirect=1#comment3826586_1867922) in the past.

I have the following function to maximise for $x,y$
$$f(x,y)=a_1 \cos(x) +b_1 \sin(x)+a_2 \cos(y) +b_2 \sin(y)+ a_3 \cos(y-x) +b_3 \sin(y-x)$$

I could not come with an idea for a closed form solution, therefore I am wondering if there is any numerical method for maximising these kind of nonlinear/sine functions. In general, when we have sum of multiple sine functions, is there any numerical method to maximise/minimise them?

P.S. Note that $\cos(\cdot)$ functions are maximised at $x=y=0$ and $\sin(\cdot)$ functions are maximised at $x=y=\pi/2$, therefore the $f(x,y)$ is concave in $0<x,y<\pi/2$ and so itt has a maximum in $0<x,y<\pi/2$.

Any reference/help/hint will be a appreciated

Comment: $f(x,y) = A_1 \cos(x+\phi_1)+ A_2 \cos(y+\phi_2)+ A_3 \cos(x-y+\phi_3)$ so it is just the sum of 3 sinusoids in $\mathbb{R}^2$ of same frequency but different directions and amplitudes. Cancelling the partial derivatives you can express $y^*$ in term of $x$. And I think solving first the two terms with largest $A_j$ will give a good starting point for the gradient descent. Even easier, you can sample $[0,\pi/2]\times[0,\pi/2]$  uniformly in $8 \times 8$ points, and select the largest as a starting point for the gradient descent, it should work too.